# Drive MOSFET by a 24V input signal of an industrial controller

Tags: mosfet

I want to drive [this n-type MOSFET](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1670317.pdf) by a 24V input Signal. Because of the max being Vgs=20V I want to set Vgs to 10V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQRsjp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this ok for building the circuit or do you have any other suggestions?

(Switching frequency <2Hz)

An alternative for the MOSFET presented above is [this one](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfz24vpbf.pdf).

Comment: You'd be better off using the build in schematic editor to make that readable.

Comment: Congratulations!  It'll work, or so it appears... :-) It would help if you'd add proper reference designations and values to **all** of the components.

Comment: Thank you, the schematic editor is many times more suitable... I don't really know the type of the other devices. I think D2 will be 1N5819, D1 a standard 10V-z-diode, M1 is a given motor with 3.3V and 3A power characteristic and SW1 an 24V-output of a PLC control.

Comment: Just as an aside, the circuit would work a little better (the gate capacitance would discharge more quickly) if you changed R1 to 470 ohms, plus you could then get rid of the Zener.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a mosfet driver is more suitable for this kind of applications.
You have an exemple of an mosfet driver http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an53.pdf.

Comment: At 2Hz, and with the switch driving a MOSFET driver, a MOSFET driver would be way overkill.